# How to remove repeated code in constructors?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have the following code;

```
abstract class Animal{

    public String name;
    public int legCount;

    //If has no leg count
    public Animal(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.legCount = 4;  //Default leg count is 4

        System.out.println("Created animal: " + name);
    }

    //If has a leg count
    public Animal(String name, int legCount){
        this.name = name;
        this.legCount = legCount;

        System.out.println("Created animal: " + name);
    }}
```

I have repeated **System.out.println("Created animal: " + name);** twice. Is there a way to remove this repeated code, so it only runs once? having multiple constructors can make this a bit of a pain.

Comment: 1 constructor can call the other. Each overloaded constructor should just set a particular value and then call the next constructor in the chain until you get to the main one that sets all the variables.

Answer (score 10):

```
class Animal{

    public String name;
    public int legCount;


    public Animal(String name){
        this(name,4);
    }

    public Animal(String name, int legCount){
        this.name = name;
        this.legCount = legCount;
        System.out.println("Created animal: " + name);
    }


}
```

**now you only repeat the printing line once**

the 1 parameter constructor call the 2 parameters constructor with the default value 4.

Answer (score 5):

In your constructor that only takes a name, have it delegate to the other constructor by calling:

```
public Animal(String name){
    this(name, 4);
}
```

This will delegate to the other constructor so that none of the code is repeated.  This will not only have only one line of code that calls `System.out.println`, it will also have only one line of code that assigns to `name` and only one line of code that assigns to `legCount`.

Answer (score -1):

The question has already been answered:

**Simply link all your constructors to one single constructor that would eventually execute your command.** One thing that is worthy of note, however, is to make sure none of the constructors have the same [signature](https://www.quora.com/Whats-a-signature-of-a-constructor). This is very important! If one constructor takes in two String parameters, there should be no other constructor that accepts two Strings. Java forbids multiple constructors with the same parameters.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!